# Setting Up MySQL Database On Google Cloud SQL In Nodejs Application

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How to set up MySQL Database On Google Cloud SQL in NodeJs Application ?
This will help you out setting up SQL database on google cloud to connect you nodejs application.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's a quick solution...

1. Open GCP
2. In the **Storage** section select **SQL**
3. Select **MySQL**
4. Enter **InstanceId** and **Password**(*save it for later use*)
5. Click **Show Configuration Options** Below and In **Connectivity Section**, inside the **public IP section** there will be an option to **add network**. Include Your **Current IP** there(Check your IP https://www.whatismyip.com/)
6. Click **Create**, It will take little time
7. Create **new database** if you want by clicking **database** section
8. Create **new user** if you want by clicking **user** section, by default user will be **root** and **password** we entered earlier
9. Open Your **NodeJs App** and select **db.config.js** file to set up your **database configuration**
10. Include This

```
module.exports = {
    HOST: "<Include Instance IP Here from GCP SQL Dashboard>",
    USER: "root",  //Change user if you need by default root user
    PASSWORD: "<Password>",  // Enter Password you entered while creating instance
    DB: "<DBName>",  //Database name you want to connect with
    // Leave As it is or configure according to your need
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  };
```

11. It Will Look Like This

```
module.exports = {
    HOST: "10.5.25.2",
    USER: "root",
    PASSWORD: "rootPassword",
    DB: "testdb",
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  };
```

#### Thanks and if facing any issue reach out to me.

#### Happy To Help!

Comment: `const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});`

and I get a `ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT`, any idea why?